# Excluding '+' and '&' characters from a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, client-side-scripting

Right now I'm working on a client-side password validator that ensures that has:

- 8 characters
- An uppercase letter
- A lowercase letter
- One number

I now need to exclude two specific characters, **+** and **&**. I wasn't exactly sure where to insert this rule in my current regular expression. What would be the best approach based on what I have now?

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/
```

Comment: Why not just use a separate RegEx? If that is true, use the RegEx `(?!.*?[+&].*?)`

Comment: Just curious though, why do you not suggest including it in the current RegEx? Overly verbose?

Comment: I'd actually suggest _not_ separating it into another regex. Anyway, where exactly do you want to exclude `+` and `&`?

Comment: Yes. It is much simpler to just do another evaluation. Maybe not on a longer string, but defiantly of this. Trying to add it to the current RegEx would take a while and over-complicate it. Well actually, you could add it at the beginning.....

Comment: Are you sure of just 1 number, 1 lower case and 1 upper case ? Because that won't add to 8 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match anything except `+`, `&` and `\n`

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[^+&\n]{8,}$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY0rO1/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Since your example is lookahead based, it makes sense to now just add a *negative* lookahead to preclude `&` or `+`:

```
/^(?!.*(\+|&))(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/
```

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/kC1wE1/3)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to exclude characters `+` and `&`. You just need to mention what you want to match i.e `[A-Za-z0-9]`

**Regex:** `^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV6vR4/1)**